# Send file via CurlFIle in PHP to google Virtual Machine

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm trying to send via **CURLFILE** in **PHP** a file whose name is *backup.zip* to a *google VM (virtual machine)*. However, we execute the process and the file does not reach the Final directory. The same script works locally and on a hostgator hosting.

The script below is for the CURL that sends:

```
$file = 'backup.zip';

$ch = curl_init();
$cfile = new CURLFile($file,$file);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => $cfile, 'filename'=>'name'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://registrobr.com.br/vdev/upload.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Below is the code that receives the information via **CURL** *(upload.php)*:

```
$folder = './Final/';
$path = $folder . $_FILES['file']['name']; 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded";
}
```

Comment: do you mean the file is called `name`? that's because of `'filename'=>'name'`.. sidenote you need to tighten the receiving script, one could fine it and upload a php script

Comment: What do you mean by "does not reach the final directory"? Is your file on another directory? Or is there an error? If there is an error, you could edit your question to add the message.